# Setting up a Python project for packaging and distribution via Homebrew

Tags: python, homebrew, python-packaging

I'm trying to create a Homebrew formula for a Python project.

Here's the Homebrew formula:

```rb
class Scanman < Formula
  include Language::Python::Virtualenv

  desc "Using LLMs to interact with man pages"
  url "https://github.com/nikhilkmr300/scanman/archive/refs/tags/1.0.1.tar.gz"
  sha256 "93658e02082e9045b8a49628e7eec2e9463cb72b0e0e9f5040ff5d69f0ba06c8"

  depends_on "python@3.11"

  def install
    virtualenv_install_with_resources
    bin.install "scanman"
  end

  test do
    # Simply run the program
    system "#{bin}/scanman"
  end
end
```

Upon running the application with the installed scanman version, it fails to locate my custom modules housed within the src directory.

```bash
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

Any insights into why this is happening?

Here's my directory structure if that helps:

```bash
.
├── requirements.txt
├── scanman
├── scanman.rb
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── cli.py
    ├── commands.py
    ├── manpage.py
    ├── rag.py
    └── state.py
```

The main executable is `scanman`. It's a Python script that lets you interact with man pages using an LLM.

It's worth noting the following:

- When I run the local version of `scanman` from my repository, it works absolutely fine.
- Other 3rd party packages installed from PyPI don't throw any error. I can't find them in `/usr/local/Cellar/scanman/1.0.1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/`, however.

Comment: Show the actual `scanman` program, you might be invoking the wrong Python (i.e. not the Python that's inside the venv created by Homebrew).

Comment: That said, there are a few other problems here. It's strongly not recommended to turn `src` itself into a package by putting `src/__init__.py` in there. At minimum, you would `PYTHONPATH=src` inside your `scanman` script. This way, Python searches _inside_ `src/` for modules, so when you run `import cli`, then Python looks for `src/cli.py`. This is analogous to setting the `-I` and `-L` C compiler flags, or `GEM_PATH` in Ruby. Making `src` itself a package defeats the whole purpose of putting your Python code inside `src`, which is to _prevent_ Python from finding it without explicit control.

Comment: If you can just rename `src/` to `scanman_lib/` and adjust your `src.__` imports to `scanman_lib.__`, then you'll be following a more typical Python convention. Just make sure to set `PYTHONPATH`  inside the `scanman` to whatever directory contains that `scanman/` directory.

Comment: With regard to your comment about invoking the wrong Python: `scanman` has `#! /usr/bin/env python3` as the shebang line. Maybe that's what is causing the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's likely part of the problem. I will try to elaborate in an answer. Please do include that info + at least a summary of what the `scanman` script is (it wasn't even obvious that it was a Python script). Your Git repo will not be easily archivable alongside this question.

Comment: I edited the title and tags to better reflect the content of the question. Feel free to revert if you disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the repo and saw that `scanman` itself is a Python script.

You actually have two problems:

1. You set `packages=find_packages(where="src")` in `setup.py`, which tells Setuptools (the program that reads `setup.py` and builds your package) to install everything *inside of* `src`. Therefore your modules `cli.py`, `commands.py`, etc. will all end up installed as top-level modules, which you'd access as `import cli`, `import commands`. That's probably not what you want.
2. As discussed in the comments, your shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python3` is at the mercy of whatever is in `PATH`, which might not even be managed by Homebrew, let alone the specific venv created by Homebrew for your package.

I elaborated on some more packaging issues and a possible simple resolution in the comments. If you're using an LLM for this work, use a different one, because it's giving you bad advice. You *should not* make a Pip-installable package called `src`. You *should* strive to make it so that Python can find your code without any additional env vars or other messing around. You also don't want to rewrite your code. My suggestions here are meant to achieve all of those things.

It looks like you are already attempting to make a Pip-installable package, so rather than messing around trying to make your current setup work, I will illustrate how to do that in a way that doesn't make a mess, and follows standard longstanding conventions.

Your file structure will look like this:

```
./
  Formula/
    scanman.rb
  .gitignore
  requirements.txt
  setup.py
  src/
    scanman/
      __init__.py
      __main__.py
      cli.py
      commands.py
      manpage.py
      rag.py
      state.py
```

The absence of the top-level `scanman` script is deliberate. Keep reading.

And your `setup.py` becomes:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="scanman",
    description="Using LLMs to interact with man pages",
    url="https://github.com/nikhilkmr300/scanman",
    author="Nikhil Kumar",
    author_email="nikhilkmr300@gmail.com",
    license="MIT",
    packages=find_packages(where="src"),
    install_requires=[
        "faiss-cpu",
        "langchain",
        "langchain-openai",
        "langchainhub",
        "openai",
        "termcolor"
    ],
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "scanman = scanman.__main__:main",
        ]
    },
)
```

Note that this is *almost* identical to what you had before.

Then:

1. Change all of your imports with `src.cli`, `src.manpage` etc. to `scanman.cli`, `scanman.manpage`.
2. Move the contents of your `scanman` script to a *function* inside the script `src/scanman/__main__.py`, and remove the shebang line.
   . Run `pip install --editable .` in your developer environment (ideally a venv!). This only needs to be run once, you do not need to re-run this when you update your code.

Your resulting `src/scanman/__main__.py` script will look like this:

```py
import argparse
import logging
import os
import readline
import sys

from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferWindowMemory
from termcolor import colored

from scanman.cli import prompt
from scanman.commands import Command
from scanman.manpage import Manpage
from scanman.rag import ERROR_MSG, ask, load_retriever
from scanman.state import State


def main():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)

    ...  # all the stuff that was under the if-name-main block


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note that you don't need both `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)` and `logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)`. Log levels are hierarchical; whatever you set on the root logger (which is what `logging.basicConfig(level=...)` does) will propagate to all other loggers, unless you explicitly set a different level on those other loggers.

As a test, you should be able to run both `python -m scanman` and `scanman` using your developer environment:

```bash
# Create a fresh venv and install into it:
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3 -m venv ./venv-testing
./venv-testing/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt .

# Both should now work:
./venv-testing/bin/scanman
./venv-testing/bin/python -m scanman
```

The reason that we like the `src/` layout is to hide your source code from the Python search path, so that you are 100% sure you are only running the version of your code that is installed in your venv, *not* whatever you happen to have in your Git repo at the time you run your code. This improves the chances that your code will work on other people's machines.

Finally, I suggested moving the Homebrew formula to the `Formula/` directory because that's standard in Homebrew, and it makes clear that `scanman.rb` is a Homebrew formula, rather than another project script.

---

There are also some things you did *correctly* in your repo that I want to call out!

First, you only set your logging config in the main script, not in the library code. That's good, because you shouldn't be trying to modify global application state from inside the library code.

It also looks like you're using `pip-compile` or `pip freeze` to emit the `requirements.txt`. That's a *great* idea. Keep doing that! Sadly I don't know how to get Homebrew to actually install dependencies from that file, as opposed to just using your declared package deps in `setup.py` with full dependency resolution. You might need to ask in the Homebrew forum for that. Ideally, Homebrew would run something like this:

```bash
$VENV_DIR/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt ./
```

But that would require it to clone your repo before installing, rather than simply installing directly from Github via Pip.